# It's so inconvinient! Why not separating?

Tags: discussion

I don't understand why not having a separate site for Python, another one for Java, another on for Perl and so on? Every time I am asking a Python-related question, I always have to mention Python in the title to let people know the context of my question, which makes the title quite long and harder to read.

Plus, if I have many questions on Python, I have to add that "python" tag every time, which is also quite cumbersome and inconvenient in case with many questions. It would be much easier for me just to go to a Python-dedicated SE site, where I would feel safe in terms of people's understanding in what context I am talking.

Also, it would be much easier for me to look for the answer to my question (in case it's already been answered) on one separate only-for-python Q&A site. I would be sure then (while looking through all the answers) that I am not going to run into a question, in which Python is mentioned only as a side note or is mentioned (even in the title) together with other programming languages only for the purpose of generalizing about programming languages without "diving" into anyone of them.

Why not do what they did on [Daniweb](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/)? I don't mean splitting StackOverflow into all those categories, but at least some of them would work as separate Q&A sites. Here is the list of their categories - they seem to work well there:

> **Hardware and Software:**
>
> Microsoft Windows
>   Linux and Unix
>   PC Hardware
>   Apple
>   Networking
>   Netbooks, Tablets and Mobile Devices
>   Home Theater / Home Entertainment
>
> **Software Development:**
>
> C++
>   C
>   Java
>   C#
>   VB.NET
>   Python
>   Perl
>   Shell Scripting
>   Assembly
>   Pascal and Delphi
>   Visual Basic 4 / 5 / 6
>   XML, XSLT and XPATH
>   Legacy and Other Languages
>   Computer Science
>   Game Development
>   Mobile Development
>
> **Web Development:**
>
> PHP
>   ASP.NET
>   ColdFusion
>   ASP
>   JSP
>   Ruby
>   RSS, Web Services and SOAP
>   Javascript / DHTML / AJAX
>   Existing Scripts
>   Databases
>   Web Design
>
> **Internet Marketing:**
>
> Promotion and Marketing Plans
>   Social Media and Online Communities
>   Advertising Sales Strategies
>   eCommerce
>   Pay-Per-Click Advertising
>   Search Engine Optimization
>
> **Business Exchange:**
>
> Hardware Swap
>   Post your Resume
>   Project Partners Wanted
>   Show Off your Projects
>   Website Reviews
>   Webmaster Marketplace
>   Looking to Hire
>
> **Community Center:**
>
> Community Introductions
>   IT Professionals' Lounge
>   Geeks' Lounge
>   DaniWeb Community Feedback
>   Area 51
>   Contribute Hot News Tips

Comment: Have you tried [filtering the questions by the python tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)?

Comment: @yhw42: Of course, I have. The procedure is quite helpful, but it doesn't filter python-as-a-side-note or python-and-others questions. On a separate Python site, I would not have to do python-tag filtering at all!

Comment: Considering the general philosophy on SE to separate topics like webmasters, serverfault, doctype, SO, unix/linux (not complaining, but splitting seems to be on the rise even on many overlapping topics), I don't see why this post is not a good suggestion, or atleast a good satire :)

Comment: @JP19: "or at least a good satire :)" - Just in case: I was quite sincere in asking this question. I didn't mean to imply any sarcasm whatsoever.

Comment: Too kind to -1.

Comment: @andrewk: "Too kind to -1" - What do you mean?

Comment: @brilliant do you see how many downvotes you got? it could get worse..but it won't.

Comment: @andrewk: Why am I getting down votes on this question? Was I being rude in asking it? Did I offend anyone? Did I say anything I was not supposed to say?

Comment: @brillant: Downvotes on Meta mean something different than they do on SO, or the other SE sites. Here, they just mean "I disagree with your suggestion". Don't take it personally.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta: I see. Thank you!

Comment: As for your *Every time I am asking a Python-related question, I always have to mention Python in the title* — tagging should suffice. (And even when the word is in the title, the tag is required too, for better searching.)

Comment: [Here's the best idea.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94591/13295)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

see

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/factionalism-site-or-tag/

Although this is hilarious, because usually the complaint is the other way around: people think they want to talk about *everything* on one site.

Comment: Thanks for this link. I am reading it.

Answer (score 3):

So mentioning a *tag* is more inconvenient than

- Having to look up the right site for each and every question ("Shell scripting", "Existing Scripts", "VBScript" or "Microsoft Windows?")
- A plethora of botched migrations ("Microsoft Windows! No, Shell Scripting! No, existing scripts!")
- Having to memorize a different URL for every site ( `shellscripting.stackoverflow.com`)
- Having thirty-eight separate accounts with badges and reputation counts
- Having thirty-eight different inboxes to look into

?

Comment: @ Pekka: (1) “Having to look up the right site for each and every question” – Isn’t it what we are doing now anyway? For example, if I need to ask a question about Photography, I look up the photography.se, and if I want to ask a question about English, I look up the English.se. What’s the problem here? Finding the link to the right site at the bottom of any SE website is not a problem at all.

Comment: @ Pekka: (2) Thus, if I have a bunch of questions about Python, I would simply go to that python.se site and ask them all there. Again what’s the problem with “looking up the right site”? “Having to memorize a different URL for every site” – Why on earth would I need to memorize a URL for each site?! Just as I said – scroll down to the bottom and simply click on the right link – it doesn’t hurt at all. That’s what users are

Comment: @ Pekka: (3) doing now anyway when they go from one SE site to another, and they don’t have to memorize URL’s. It would hurt even if the number of links at the bottom is 30 times bigger – if they are located in alphabetical order it would still be quite easy to find the right link.

Comment: @ Pekka: (4) “Having thirty-eight separate accounts with badges and reputation counts” – Is the process of accruing badges and reputation not automated? Do you mean to say moderators’ validation is required each time a new badge is given to a certain user or that user’s comment gets up-voted?! :) Are you really being serious here?

Comment: @ Pekka: (5) “Having thirty-eight different inboxes to look into” – Don’t you have one inbox that collects all the answers to your questions from all SE sites? Well, I DO have such one, and I think all the others do, too. Perhaps, you mean that case when you use a different name for each site, but that’s not my case – I use only one name on all SE sites and all my accounts are associated.

Comment: @ Pekka: (6) I am sorry to say that, but all the points that you have brought up here in favor of non-splitting policy seem quite weak to me. The link that Jeff Atwood gave me leads to a way more serious presentation of this matter with way more valid points.

Comment: @brilliant the bottom line is that this is an insane idea. If Jeff argues that point in a better way (I wouldn't be surprised if he does), I'm perfectly happy with that.

Comment: @ Pekka: (7) “if you start splitting every SE site into 50 sub-sites, you're going to end up with thousands of sites” – Why thousands? Look at those categories that I have mentioned in my question. Are there thousands categories there? Not even a hundred! Plus, I was speaking about splitting according to programming languages. The number of major programming languages being discussed is even smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Because a lot of quesions overlap more then one "topic" ....  However you group tags into topics together this will be a problem for programming quesions.