# Is a mini-site approach a solution to these Area 51 proposals?

Tags: discussion, mini-site

TL;DR Subtopics of sites in beta are themselves heading towards beta.  Is the sub-site method not a more appropriate implementation?  Comments both on [Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2924/39953) and [B&CG](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/573/why-has-the-proposed-magicthe-gathering-site-entered-the-commit-phase/575#575) that seem to indicate that the people who are interested in these topics believe this would be a good solution instead of separate sites.  The responders in this [Game of Go thread](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3317/virtual-subsite-for-go) have specific concerns that would need to be addressed.

I will open this discussion with an acknowledgement that the mini-site idea that was implemented for Facebook has been specifically noted as unlikely to appear on other SE 2.0 sites.

With that out of the way I would like to suggest that it could be exactly the solution that could help Board & Card Games.  [This question on Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/83/39953), and [this answer](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83/game-specific-sites/296#296) highlight part of the issue - there are many proposals to start game specific SE 2.0 sites alongside B&CG; Go and Magic the Gathering gaining a lot of steam.

I can see their point, to some degree, that users looking for specific information on a particular game will look for a specialized site as opposed to a general one.  I believe gaming.SE also fights this particular problem.

There are a couple of specific proposals that could likely bring in a reasonable number of users to B&CG, the one that has my attention in particular is the [Magic the Gathering](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2922/39953)
proposal.  Another, which **has established a 100% commitment level** and is being prepared for beta is [the Game of Go](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11942/game-of-go).

What is to the point is that there are large audiences for these topics, and bringing more of that traffic here with quality Q&A seems to fit with the stated goals of the Stack Exchange network.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Although I focus on Magic:The Gathering in this particular question, I also believe Poker to be an excellent candidate for this treatment.

Comment: For those looking for further insight, this comment on the SE 1.0 site asserts 1,500 unique visitors per day http://draw3cards.wordpress.com/2011/08/26/we-need-your-help-looking-for-co-foundersco-owners/

Comment: According to http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5220/board-and-card-games B&CG's public beta attracts less than 500 per day.

Comment: It's similar for game-of-go which is about to hit beta

Comment: Related (with additional ideas for mini-sites that haven't been implemented in the Facebook minisite): [Introduce sub-communities (or “Portals”) to prevent fragmentation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94591) (Edit: Eeeek! The images have gone missing, they contain most of the suggestions. They seem to be gone, rats)

Comment: This sounds like a great idea to get proposals that are weak (but have a strong sense of community) off the ground.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I don't think it'll be that big an issue to allow these sub-sites to try and prosper in beta. Either they'll do well enough to warrent leaving them open, or they'll flounder and get shut down (and hopefully the questions moved to B&CG).

The fact that they got to beta shows some conviction on the community behind the proposals, so maybe they really don't want to be a part of this site.