# Code of the week?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow

After seeing [Photography Stack Exchange](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) for the first time,  I noticed that they have a [picture of the week](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1739/official-picture-of-the-week-themes) event, which got me thinking, "How about Stack Overflow have a 'Code snippet of the week'" or something like that. Anyway, it's just an idea, something to give Stack Overflow some more razzle-dazzle.

What do you think, and would this be something that would be accepted by the community?

Note, I'm *not* talking about code challenges, [code golf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) or anything like that. Just four(ish) lines of code from an question/answer picked by the community to display at the top of the site for a week, (or something similar).

Comment: While I like this idea, I'm not sure how it could be implemented without being more work than it's worth

Comment: Basically the opposite of The Daily WTF? :)

Comment: Code doesn't have the type of objective beauty that photographs do. Answers that are highly upvoted may have code that works well to solve a difficult problem, but that doesn't necessarily mean it is beautiful and worthy of display. In fact, working code is often *not* all that pretty.

Comment: What language? All of them?

Comment: @Oded Well, maybe to start with just the most popular languages.

Comment: @Sam - measured how?

Comment: By the amount of jQuery @Oded. D'uh.

Comment: Question/Answer of the week perhaps; code of the week doesn't sound like it even has anything to do with SO.

Comment: @Oded - Something like, the most questions & answers.

Comment: @Joe - Yeah, i think that sounds better, then code of the week. And probably more appropriate.

Comment: @Bart - Right. That settles the language question.

Comment: @Joe - we already have a weekly newsletter...

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback, i see now with hindsight that's not a great idea. ;)

Comment: Since you're new to Meta, please allow me to point out that [downvotes work a little differently here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). People are not saying that this is such a dumb idea that you shouldn't have posted it, or that you did anything wrong. They're just saying that they disagree with it. So don't let a large negative number scare you too much!

Comment: Sure, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: As far as promoting a specific code snippet, most of the code posted to Stack Overflow is bad, *bad* code. In fact, it's usually posted to Stack Overflow **because** it's bad code, and needs fixing. I can't imagine we'd want to showcase anything that gets posted here, unless it's specifically to call out some particularly subtle or common error.

Comment: It's an interesting idea. The problem with this on SO would be that some code of Jon Skeet's would be chosen every single week.

Comment: @JoshCaswell You're probably right.

Comment: This would be better than the current Hot Questions list actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

eh, I'm not really seeing the point honestly. If the point is just to give SO some "razzle dazzle", its just going to be noise. SO doesn't need any to convey its message and its aesthetically pleasing enough as is.

If the point is to be an excellent example of how to write code properly, why have a weekly version when you can just have a link in the How-To-Ask section on how to post good code and you have the entire Internet to ask? Besides, as posted in the comments, there's a lot of subjectivity on what constitutes "good code".

I would agree that its a good idea to practice reading other's code but this would just detract from what SO really is. There's a lot of great questions and answers that don't involve posting code and this seems like it would leave those out.

Answer (score 5):

We already have something like this: The [Week Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=week) shows hottest questions of the week.

Comment: I just realized that the Week Tab is  decidedly more useful than the hot questions list.

Answer (score 3):

I like the sentiment behind your idea. Smaller sites have the luxury of doing a *lot* more community building oriented things than Stack Overflow does; that's been eating at me ever since I was elected to be a moderator a couple of years ago, and has continued to eat at me after being hired by Stack Exchange.

We used to have some weekly 'fun' with something we called [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), which originally appeared on Stack Overflow itself until we decided that it was a little more excitement than [our steely, business like smiles](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/) could take.

I like the idea of getting users interested in work other users are doing in an extra curricular way so long as it does not detract from the main goal of the site. For that, what we'd need are small, community organized contests and challenges where they pay off is just the enjoyment of having a bit of fun with some distant colleagues.

How that could work, and more to the point *where* that could work is a completely different discussion, but I did want to chime in to say that what you're *after* is a good thing, it's just that getting there is kind of hard.

Comment: Given the size of SO, this would have to be organized around [some kind of sub-community](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94591/introduce-sub-communities-or-portals-to-prevent-fragmentation), probably by language tag. It would be awesome to see something in that vein.