# Too many questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Every minute there are several questions asked on Stackoverflow. Even in the features section there are more then 400 questions. I believe because of this some questions do not get the attention they deserve since even in the unanswered section they get blown off the front page in a matter of minutes. Maybe we can come up with something that prevents this.

Does anyone agree Stackoverflow is getting too busy and therefor unorganized? And how should this be fixed? I have thought of a view things.

I have thought about splitting up Stackoverflow into web and normal programming. There are also plenty of tags used here that pretty much can go straight into superuser SE. I am sure this requires a lot of logistics and is huge task overall.

Enable to bump questions to top, essentially renew them might make things worse. If a user is allowed to bump a question every 24 hours or more might help to get a bit more attention without using bounty. <10 reputation users that just post once and never return, will not bump questions and thus not need more attention. There could also be a reputation requirement for bumping posts.

Comment: Are there really all that many clear, well-asked questions going unanswered? I doubt it. And when looking for questions to answer, I usually limit myself to those tags I'm interested in anyway. And then there are the ignored tags. So do we actually have a problem?

Comment: Yes i think so, or at least SE could make things more organized by migrating some tags.

Comment: If they are perfectly on-topic for the site? Nah. Even when we get new sites that have an overlap with SO we don't migrate the existing content there.

Comment: Browse by your favourite language tags, or by the front page which chooses for you. Directly browsing by the unfiltered questions list is like drinking from a fire hose.

Comment: Yet it takes quite some time to fill a favorite tag list, 10 * to fill your personal ignore list for the average person on stack overflow. For someone just crossing this site it is like drinking from a firehose with the back end in the sewer. Try to see things out of your own perspective.

Comment: @Menno if you split it up how do people choose which part to use; the same way people use tags

Comment: @RichardTingle Good one, but i think there are two fronts here on stackoverflow. I already mentioned them, app/game programmers and web programmers. I don't know how to get stats from this website but that might cut the problem in half.

Comment: @AlienArrays Believe me i would not, but luckily this is meta :D. I try to keep my questions to a minimum at stackoverflow though ;)

Comment: Some related discussion at: [It's so inconvinient! Why not separating?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75766/its-so-inconvinient-why-not-separating).

Comment: Well it's too bad nobody seem to agree, at least that is for all advanced users. I truly believe there can be major improvements be made, especially for newcomers and less advanced users. I don't see anyone putting up a solid reason why not to do anything about this and like on every SE site people look at stuff only from there own perspective, with tunnel vision.

Answer (score 6):

I disagree that there is a problem.  I can usually find questions I want to answer, when I am in the mood to answer and have the time by using my favorite tags and filtering questions.

But for the sake of argument, let's do the math on one of your ideas.

> Enable to bump questions to top, essentially renew them might make things worse. If a user is allowed to bump a question every 24 hours or more might help to get a bit more attention without using bounty. <10 reputation users that just post once and never return, will not bump questions and thus not need more attention. There could also be a reputation requirement for bumping posts

There are 76,875 unanswered questions that are less than 1 month old (12/14/13 to 1/14/14) right now.  What if a quarter of those users decided to bump one question once a day until they get an answer.  That comes to roughly 13 questions get bumped every minute, or almost 1 question every 3-4 seconds.  How would that benefit the site?  It would basically drown out even more new questions so more questions need to get bumped.  Limiting based on rep will only limit the noise, but it will still be noise.

And generally speaking questions that don't get answered usually are poor quality questions, or questions that are impossible to answer, so all you are doing is drowning the site in poor quality questions that keep getting bumped.

Comment: Yes you are a 17.3K stackoverflow who knows how it works. About the bumping, i figured the same, it might make things worse. That is why i suggested a migration of tags.

Answer (score 4):

That is not correct. Usually users have their favorite tags added to their list, which make it easy to get noticed question even if it is not on the top page of new question.

Beside this there are many things to get question noticed, like editing post with details get bounce to active list, adding bounty, share feature. Bounty make that question to featured list for 7 days, if it stills not get the answer there is different case.

If you see unanswered list there are still many views to those question, reason is only either the post is not clear or the problem is that complex that very few people can solve it.

Comment: So i should edit my questions with nonsense to get onto the active list? Because if i put one down i try to make it as complete as possible. Now a harder/more complicated and less interesting new question gets 10 views if none of the viewers make a comment chances are big it gets drowned in the list.

Comment: Editing your post with nonsense sounds like a good path to community wiki, as others edit it to return to sanity.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree strongly with the comment that there are too many questions. I would like there to be more questions. Especially more questions that I have the ability to answer.

Also, I'd like to say that StackOverflow is VERY organized. Yes it took my a little time to add all those ignore tags. But it was definitely worth it since I don't have to ever see the questions that I know I won't be able to answer.

If for some reason I do want to see all the questions, I just have to go my profile and uncheck the "hide ignored tags" checkbox. If I learn something new and can answer questions for that, then I simply remove that tag from the ignored tags.

Also, if you don't want to add that many ignore tags, you can just favorite the tags you want to answer or interested in seeing questions for, and they will be highlighted to bring your attention to them.

I would like to suggest the following:

**That there be an option to hide all questions that are not in your favorite tags.**

This way, others that don't want to see all those questions, like I didn't, won't have to ignore so many tags like I did. They could simply add 2, 5, 20 tags, and then check a checkbox to hide all other tags.

Here are my favorite tags:

[image]

Here are my ignored tags (added black background for visibility reasons):

[image]

Comment: And THIS is exactly what i mean. You have your account beautifully organized, congratulations you are a very orderly and organized person. Now i bet most of the users do not have a list like that. Let alone for new people, this site looks like the garbage dump of the inter webs. Yet. I'd say stackoverflow has the potential to be very organized but that takes a organized and advanced user in the first place.

Comment: Indeed, but that still requires a user to fill in there favorite tags. Personally i did this a long time after registering, but now it is really necessary to navigate the site.